# Why this informal proof of Recursion Theorem not rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis

I've been studying analysis these days. I think the "informal" proof of the Recursion Theorem in Tao's *Analysis* is rigorous enough. (The material is in the official sample page, which is public.)

It claims that the definition of $f_n$ is well-defined, with the usage of the Peano postulates and the mathematical induction. I think it is rigorous enough, but still finding a more lengthy proof of it in other book. What's the problem with this proof?
[image]

ref: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/

Comment: Informal and rigorous are not antonymous, nor incompatible. I think Tao's definition is informal because it defines "recursive definitions" with human-readable words rather than with axioms of set theory.

Answer (score 1):

One way in which this is not a rigorous proof from e.g. Peano arithmetic is that no conditions have been put on the form of the function $f$, but of course if you actually wanted to write down this proof in Peano arithmetic then at a minimum $f$ would need to be a function you can talk about in Peano arithmetic.

In addition, a typical statement of, say, first-order induction in Peano arithmetic is the claim, for every predicate $\varphi$, that

> If $\varphi(0)$ is true and $\varphi(n) \Rightarrow \varphi(n+1)$, then $\forall n : \varphi(n)$.

This form of induction does not immediately allow you to make inductive definitions; it is immediately suited to writing down inductive proofs. You somehow need $\varphi(n)$ to be the claim "$a_n$ is well-defined, and $a_n = f_{n-1}(a_{n-1})$" and it's not immediately clear how to do this; in any case the proof does not supply a way of doing this.

There are many "proofs" at this level of rigor that in fact do not work; an example that comes to mind is the [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox).